# RJ45 with LED connections

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, integrated-circuit, communication, ethernet

I am currently doing a project which uses an Ethernet connection and I want the LAN connection to be indicated using LEDs. I plan to use the SS-74810-003 from Bel-Fuse.

How do I tap the connections from the ethernet wires and give them to the LEDs without any data loss? Should I be using a microcontroller to control this process?

Comment: buy an ethernet switch that has LEDs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't. That's not the way it is done.

The LEDs can not be connected directly to Ethernet wires.

The LEDs are controlled by the Ethernet PHY chip which communicates on the link.

The PHY chip will control the LEDs based on negotiated link speed and data transnsfer, so even an MCU will not help in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I can go with some of the chips which have been mentioned in the following websites and build a circuit around it:
i)https://www.ti.com/interface/ethernet/phys/overview.html
ii)https://www.microchip.com/en-us/products/high-speed-networking-and-video/ethernet/ethernet-phys

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. But you used to be able to...sort of.

*For those who may think this answer is irrelevant because the question is about Ethernet and not RS-232, I think is very useful information, particularly for younger people who may have never encountered the old stuff and not realize that OP's question would have made total sense in a previous generation of computer technology.*

Back in ye olden times, we used serial connection - commonly referred to as RS-232, even if a particular connection didn't 100% conform to the standard. These were generally powerful enough that you could slap an LED in-line with a connection for monitoring with no ill effects at all. In fact, common tools for testing/configuring/trouble-shooting serial connections, [such as this one *still available* at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005H46XS2):

[image: RS232 breakout box]

used LEDs driven directly by the signal and control lines. I have (or had, not sure if I tossed them all) some of these breakout boxes. Note that Amazon says they are "battery powered". Actually, these did not have any batteries - they were entirely powered by the devices being connected/tested.

But back to the current (pun intended) situation. Many, but not all, Ethernet switches and Ethernet interface cards include one or two LEDs to indicate connection (link integrity), speed (e.g., 100M vs. 1G) and transmission (blinking). But with the much higher speed of Ethernet (serial was typically 300 bps - 115,000 bps, typical 19,200 bps), lower voltage (serial originally 12V, later 5V, but Ethernet as little as +/- 1V) and much more complex signalling methods, throwing LEDs inline will simply not work.

Comment: Well, even if from voltage/current perspective it would be high enough to drive LEDs directly from Ethernet, you could not tell apart a 100MBps link transmitting data symbols or just constantly transmitting IDLE symbols. Regardless what used to be possible with other interfaces, the answer is still no to the question asked.

Comment: I was initially surprised these are still made and sold, but really serial's still out there doing its thing, slowly.   I had a heck of a time finding an AT-female to PS2-male adapter recently, only one hit on aliexpress.

Comment: @Criggie I might still have a few in my office. I did toss a box of stuff recently. Though I still have a box of baseball cards from 40 years ago...they'll be worth something someday :-)

Comment: @Criggie RS-232 is still very common in industrial settings for its sheer simplicity and the noise-resistance it has from the high signal levels. (±15 V is a lot more than most noise sources will couple onto wires, even in a light industrial environment!) It's also used as a fallback "lowest common denominator" for electronics test automation, for when you can't afford to spend the extra $500 to get the LXI or GPIB option on your whatever-it-is.

Comment: In early 2011 we had a couple of significant quakes locally, and for a while there was a no-go zone in the CBD.  A bunch of horse-trading went on between techs, those who had a working tape drive and those who had their customer's backup but no drive able to read it.  All those weird old scsi cables and adapters were of use.  I even helped someone because I had a 5.25" HDD floppy drive.  Upshot - NEVER throw anything out.